# Getting timeout when comparing GetAttribute on Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

I am quite new with protractor and javascript and I am having an issue when I compare a string with an attribute value. The message on console is: function timed out after 30000 milliseconds. In the Protractor API says that I don't need to create a function when expecting for a condition. When I create the function and print the element, I get the right value, but when I try to compare with expect I got 'TypeError: getAttribute is not thenable' Does anyone have any tip ?

**Class Elements:**

```
'use strict';

var protractor = require('protractor');
var element = protractor.element;
var by = protractor.by;

function Elements() {
    return {
        getDate: function() {
            return element(by.id('visit-date'));
        }
    };
}

module.exports = Elements;
```

**Class Assertions:**

```
'use strict';

var Elements = require('./elements');
var protractor = require('protractor');
var browser = protractor.browser;

function Assertions() {

    var elements = new Elements();

    return {
        assertDate: function() {
            var dateElement = elements.getDate();
            return expect(dateElement.getAttribute('value')).to.eventually.contain('2015-08-26');
        },
        assertUpdatedTexts: function() {
            return this.assertDate();
        }
    };
}

module.exports = Assertions;
```

Thank you !

Comment: So I was going to say try    dateElement.getAttribute('value').then(function(attr) {
        return expect(attr).toContain("2015-08-26");  [adapted from @juliemr at https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/673], but it sounds like you know that can work but you should not need to go there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the problem, we have fixed changing the assertion date function:

```
 assertDate: function(datetime) {
            var dateElement = elements.getDate();
            var dateValue = dateElement.getAttribute('value');
            return expect(dateValue).to.eventually.contain(datetime.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        },
```

and passing the date parameter like proper dates not string:

```
 var VISIT_DATETIME = moment({y: 2016, M: 7, d: 21, h: 12, m: 20});
 var VISIT_DURATION = moment.duration({hours: 3, minutes: 20});
```

Thank you for the help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

It *looks* like you're using Mocha as your test runner? Protractor hacks Jasmine to automatically handle promises, but *not* Mocha. So use either Jasmine or handle the promises with `.then()`.